# pagination breaks old rspec tests - render throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pagination, faker

rails 4, rspec 3

I am using pagination and faker

below is an old test case that was fine before I implemented pagination and faker.

```
RSpec.describe "users/index", :type => :view do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:users, [
      User.create!(
        :name => "Name",
        :email => "Name@mail.com",
        :password => "mystrings"
      ),
      User.create!(
        :name => "Name",
        :email => "Name2@mail.com",
        :password => "mystrings"
      )
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of users" do
    render
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Name".to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Name@mail.com".to_s, :count => 1
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Name2@mail.com".to_s, :count => 1
  end
end
```

the error message:

```
 1) users/index renders a list of users
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f90b55d7828>
     # /Users/xuanliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/will_paginate-3.0.7/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb:73:in `will_paginate'
```

is there any way other than using `render` to "refresh" the current page, so that I test on the view?

I think my other problem is similar - also regarding using `render` properly.

test case:

```
RSpec.describe "users/show", :type => :view do
  before(:each) do
    @user = assign(:user, User.create!(
      :name => "Name5",
      :email => "Name5@mail.com",
      :password => "mystrings"
    ))
  end

  it "renders attributes in <p>" do
    render
    expect(rendered).to match(/Name/)
    expect(rendered).to match(/Email/)
  end
end
```

error message:

```
2) users/show renders attributes in <p>
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       The @test variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?
     # /Users/xuanliu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/will_paginate-3.0.7/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view.rb:94:in `infer_collection_from_controller'
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 2018 and this still an issue and solution yet :D

Answer (score 0):

### Error 1

The reason you got this error is this:

```
assign(:users, [
   User.create!(
     :name => "Name",
     :email => "Name@mail.com",
     :password => "mystrings"
   ),
   User.create!(
     :name => "Name",
     :email => "Name2@mail.com",
     :password => "mystrings"
   )
 ])
```

Most likely in your code, you normally assign `@users` with sth like `User.all` - this returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which is not an `Array` you assign. You should be able to get around this with:

```
User.create!(
   :name => "Name",
   :email => "Name@mail.com",
   :password => "mystrings"
 )
 User.create!(
   :name => "Name",
   :email => "Name2@mail.com",
   :password => "mystrings"
 )
assign(:users, User.all)
```

### Error 2

Apparently you use `@test` variable, which you have not assign with anything. It is impossible to say more without knowing why there is a variable called `@test` in your view.

Comment: I did not have @test variable anywhere in my code. I thought it was something generated automatically..

Comment: I tried your solution to no avail. I should also mention that I used the faker gem.. dunno that was causing the problem. updated the question. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = assign(:user, User.create!(
    :name => "Name5",
    :email => "Name5@mail.com",
    :password => "mystrings"
  ))
  assign :user, user
  assign :test, user
end
```